# Set options for JHtmlTabs with Bootstrap for joomla

Tags: joomla

According to Using the JHtmlTabs class in a component, set options may be specified for the tabs being rendered

Answer (score 0):

I have checked and find that is the solution which works for me!

```
<?php
$options = array(
    'active'    => 'tab1_id'    // Not in docs, but DOES work
);

echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.startTabSet', 'ID-Tabs-Group', $options);
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'ID-Tabs-Group', 'tab1_id', JText::_('COM_BOOTSTRAPTABS_TAB_1')); ?> 

<p>Content of the first tab.</p> 

<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.addTab', 'ID-Tabs-Group', 'tab2_id', JText::_('COM_BOOTSTRAPTABS_TAB_2')); ?>

<p>Content of the second tab.</p> 

<?php echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTab');
echo JHtml::_('bootstrap.endTabSet');?>
```